# can we have multiple aliases for a Domain Class Attribute in grails

Tags: grails, attributes, dns, alias

I have many domain classes in my application an for Audit logging I need the name attribute of each Domain class. unfortunately the name attribute is not generic in all Domains. 
In my Audt log class I get the type of object modified/created/deleted and then save the id right now (which is common code since all domains have 'id' attribute) but now if I want to get the name attribute out of the domain from the ID, each domain has a different name attribute, like Resource Domain has resourceName, User domain has userName and so on... soI will have to handle each domain seperately (like have a map or bunch of switch statements for getting the name attribute from the Domain class name).
Is there a way I can have an alias mapping for each domain class's name field to be called 'name' . there should not be any change to the actual attributes in the Domains in whatever changes I do, I can add a column to Audit Domain but not other table changes.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there's any way to do this automatically.

As you guessed, you're going to either have to change all of the domain objects so that they have a 'name' attribute, or somehow maintain a map of which attribute in each class is to be considered the 'name'.

I suppose that one answer might be to add a getName() method to each of the domain classes, and return the appropriate value from that method.

If you really don't want to modify the domain objects at all, you can use groovy meta-object programming (MOP) to inject this method into each domain class from the BootStrap class.

Comment: I can do the getName function, that looks like the most elegant way. Thanks